# iTerm2 loses "ls" colors if I ssh to a server

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, ls, iterm2

Why do I lose `ls`' colors when I ssh to a server?

I would like those colors to be preserved. Is this possible? Should one do something on the server side?

Comment: Does it work when you run `ls -G`? Does the server's shell have `CLICOLOR` and `LSCOLORS` set? (i.e. `echo $LSCOLORS`)

Comment: ls -G don't show colors. If I do ls --color I get some. I don't know if the server shell as CLICOLOR and LSCOLORS set. If I echo CLICOLOR and LSCOLORS I got an empty line with nothing displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server doesn't use a colored `ls` command by default.

You can `alias` your `ls` command to always use colors in one of the server's shell configuration files (e.g. `~/.bashrc`) with the --color=auto option.

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Some additional remarks:

- If the server runs **Linux**, the above should be enough to get colors working. You can use an [LSCOLORS generator](http://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/) to manually specify the colors in a  shell configuration file by adding:

  ```
  export LS_COLORS=…
  ```
- If the server runs **BSD / OS X**, you additionally need the following for `ls` to automatically show colors (you then don't even need to specify an alias):

  ```
  export CLICOLORS=1
  ```

  Also, here it's not `LS_COLORS`, but `LSCOLORS`, and the syntax is different (see the LSCOLORS generator output).

  ```
  export LSCOLORS=…
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I believe I have no write access but, I'm using iterm2 with solarize. If I do ls --color what colors will it use ? Can we do something like export TERM =xterm-color or we can't do this since this is on our remote machine?

Comment: It'll use the default colors specified on that machine. You can try changing the meaning of colors in iTerm's preferences though.